# Creating Array - Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown

Tags: arrays, vb.net, exception

I am using Visual Studio 2015 VB. net. When I try to create the following array, I get the error message

> "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown."

when the target CPU is x86 or AnyCPU.

When I set the target CPU to x64 the array is created fine.

```
Private maCombsNums As Integer(,,,,)
....
maCombsNums = New Integer(50, 50, 50, 50, 50) {}
```

Is this a bug? As I would like to run my program on a 32-bit windows system.

Comment: You are creating a 5 dimensional array, of 50 length per dimension. Thats 312.500.000 Integers. I dont know why on x64 works and why it does not on x86, but an Out of memory exeption is not that rare

Comment: It's asking for 1.25 Gb of memory.  Probably on 32 bit, it cannot find a contiguous area of memory that large.  You can try to use `editbin /LARGEADDRESSAWARE my.exe` after you compile in 32Bit to get up to 3Gb of memory for your app, but probably 64 Bit is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your help, Will try this out to compile the app in 32-Bit

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question you asked, this is not a bug.
You are asking for a lot of memory and x64 will be able to give you more.

You might be able to find a better data structure for your use case. For example, if the data is sparse you could use a lookup table (`Dictionary`) and just populate what you need.